# Where do I get up-to-date versions of org.eclipse.jdt for Maven?

Tags: maven, eclipse-jdt

I would like to use the Eclipse AST to generate source code. My project is managed by Maven and I would like to simply add dependencies for the compiler. Unfortunately, the most recent version I found in central is `3.3.0-v_771`. The [Tycho](http://eclipse.org/tycho/) project offers newer versions. However, I found that the poms do not specify dependencies and I don't want to do that myself. I've spent quite some time googling for other sources but that's the best I could come up with.

Does anyone know of a better, maven-compliant way of getting JDT in Maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can the use [Maven-Eclipse-Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/to-maven-mojo.html) to deploy your Eclipse bundles to Maven on your own and then use these. An example command would be:

```
mvn eclipse:to-maven -DdeployTo=internal-nexus::default::http://myNexus/content/repositories/eclipse -DeclipseDir=C:/Eclipse
```

Alternatively you could purchase a license for [Nexus Pro](http://www.sonatype.com/Nexus) and provide Eclipse p2-Repositories as Maven repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is an other way. [Some of the Eclipse Neon.2 jars are published as normal maven artifacts](https://objectteams.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/eclipse-neon-2-is-on-maven-central/) (pom files are user friendly, the standard dependency management of maven will work).

If you want to use `jdt-core` in your project you just need to add this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
  <version>3.12.2</version>
</dependency>
```

... and you let maven do the rest for your. I have published a simple example [how to use the java code formatter from eclipse in a simple java application](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://objectteams.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/eclipse-neon-2-is-on-maven-central/).